# Should a custom filter modify / update its input?

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

Say I have a custom filter like so:

```
app.filter('custom', function () {
  return function (input, search) {

    const ret = {};

    // find matches in input, given search
    ret[key] = input[key] // etc etc

    return ret;

});
```

here is the HTML, that works with the filter:

```
   <div class="row" ng-repeat="(promptId, q) in myHash | custom:searchText">
```

what I believe I need to do, is set `myHash` in the controller to the `ret` value from the custom filter?

Is that the right thing to do, if so, how can I do that?

In other words, should I do something like this:

```
   app.filter('custom', function ($scope) {
      return function (input, search) {

        const ret = {};

        // find matches in input, given search
        ret[key] = input[key] // etc etc

        return $scope.myHash = ret;   // do not do this LOL

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "[What] I believe I need to do, is set `myHash` in the controller to the `ret` value from the custom filter?"

No, that would be wrong. A filter should not modify its input. It should produce a new value derived from the input (that is, its function parameters).

From the [AngularJS documentation on filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) (emphasis added by me):

> "**The filter function should be a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)**, which means that it should always return the same result given the same input arguments and should not affect external state."

As far as I can see, you're already doing it the right way (in your first code example).

Comment: thanks, looks like Angular has this use case covered, see my answer, didn't expect this to be so straightforward.

Comment: Btw, I changed "categoryFiltered" to "myHash" because it's more clear what's going on with a better / less confusing name

Comment: this answer is correct, but doesn't show a solution

Comment: @AlexanderMills: It doesn't need to. Your question was, _"Is that the right thing to do, if so, how can I do that?"_ and I gave an answer to that: No, it isn't the right way, and since the answer to the first question is no, the second question needn't be answered. Your filter already does things the right way. If your issue is that it doesn't actually work (I figured your _"etc etc"_ comment was intended as a placeholder for code not shown in full), you should've asked about that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the following worked.

before:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(promptId, q) in myHash | custom:searchText">
```

after:

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="(promptId, q) in (myFilteredHash = (myHash | custom:searchText))">
```

So now, I have a second variable in my controller's $scope called `myFilteredHash`.

You could probably pass the $scope to the filter and then set `myFilteredHash` to the result.

I think the only thing you **shouldn't** do, is set the original value to the filtered value, because then you basically lose all your data! On top of that, you might set yourself up for an (infinite) digest loop.

Comment: To me it would seem very wrong to create a filter taking a whole `$scope` as its input.  A scope is essentially a mixed bag of state, and every scope is different. The scope of controller 1 has properties A, B, C, the scope of controller 2 has properties X, Y, Z, etc. If your filter is dependent on a scope, chances are that you are making that filter specific to its associated controller; it won't be reusable. Better to pass those properties of a scope to the filter directly that it needs, instead of passing the whole mixed bag.

Comment: Apart from that I am wondering, why do you need a variable `myFilteredHash` at all? (Btw. the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) has a somewhat similar example in the section titled, "Using filters in controllers, services, and directives".) What is wrong with your first example, where you iterate (`ng-repeat`) over an anonymous collection?

Comment: (Re: _" you might set yourself up for an (infinite) digest loop."_ You are right in principle, but in practice AngularJS will prevent just that by aborting the digest loop after 10 iterations and logging a warning to the console. It's definitely something to avoid, though.)

Comment: Our data in the front-end is stored in myHash - if we overwrite myHash, we lose the data, so we really need a separate data structure to hold the filteredItems - maybe just the keys, not the values, but a separate data structure nonetheless.

Comment: What you could do is inject the filter into your controller, then observe changes to `myHash` via `$onChanges`. There you could explicitly regenerate `myFilteredHash` using the injected filter. In your template, you'd no longer filter `myHash` but iterate over `myFilteredHash` directly. That way, instead of recreating `myFilteredHash` on every digest loop run, you'd only recreate it when `myHash` actually changes.

Comment: Thanks for that last tip, might use that info